# How to have QGraphicsScene not centered in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt

How can I manualy position a `QGraphicsScene` inside the `QGraphicsView`, because the default is always centered, but I want to position it by myself.

Comment: You can use [`QGraphicsView::setAlignment`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#alignment-prop), if that's enough for you?

Comment: @thuga Hi, I want the scene free so I can move it as I want. That will only align, but not let it free, right?

Answer (score 0):

Call the [centerOn](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn) function of QGraphicsView

> Scrolls the contents of the viewport to ensure that the scene coordinate pos, is centered in the view.

Alternatively, if you want to specify a rect of the area in the scene to be visible, you can use [fitInView](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView).